# How do I respond to a Discord bot?

Tags: python, discord.py

I want to ask the bot a question, then reply to it again, without having to create multiple answers. This is the start:

```
import discord

client = discord.Client()

@client.event
async def on_ready():
 print("Bot is ready")

@client.event
async def on_message(message):
 if message.author == client.user
  return

 msgs = message.content.startswith
```

Then I want to creat a chat strand. Like this:

```
if msgs("Restart")
 await message.channel.send("Are you sure?")
 if msgs("Yes")
  await message.channel.send("Ok")
#once the bot has asked if im sure. I want to be able to reply yes
```

Answer (score 1):

It's not clear what exactly you want to achieve, but it seems like you want to use a `wait_for` event. This would let the bot know it is waiting for a user's message that is equal to the message content in your code.

Here is a simple example, also make sure to change the check function to how you need, or leave it out, it is there only to make sure that the author which has used the command should trigger the `wait_for`, but in your case you may not need it.

```
msg = await client.wait_for('message',timeout=10,check=lambda message: message.author ==  message.author)

if msg.content.lower() == "yes":
    await message.channel.send("I'm restarting")

if msg.content.lower() == "no":
    await message.channel.send("Cancelled!")
```

Comment: I want to be able to reply to a bots question without having to code that response because then if I say Yes then it will always come up with the same response. For example. I want to be able to trigger the bot. Have it aask if I am sure. Then respond yes or no without having to code yes or no as seperate codes.